# Feathers Authentication via POST works but socket doesn't

Tags: node.js, authentication, socket.io, feathersjs

[Here is a repo](https://github.com/snewell92/newhotness) showing my latest progress, and [here is my configuration](https://github.com/snewell92/newhotness/blob/master/config/default.json). As it stands that repo now doesn't even authenticate with REST - although I think something is wrong with socket auth that needs to be looked at.

---

I configured feathers, was able to create a user REST-fully with Postman, and even get an auth token (I can post to /authenticate to get a token, and then verify that token - yay postman! yay REST api!).

But in the browser the story ain't so happy. I can use `find` to get data back, but `authenticate` just gives me errors.

In my googling I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538683/feathers-authentication-version-1-app-authenticate-not-working-with-sockets) and updated my client javascript to be [this](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-client/blob/master/dist/feathers.min.js). I have also tried doing `jwt` auth with the token from postman, but that gives the same `Missing Credentials` error. Halp!

Code incoming...

---

**app.js** (only the configuration part to show order)

```
app.configure(configuration(path.join(__dirname, '..')))
  .use(cors())
  .use(helmet()) // best security practices
  .use(compress())
  .use(favicon(path.join(app.get('public'), 'favicon.ico')))
  .use('/', feathers.static(app.get('public')))
  .configure(socketio())
  .configure(rest())
  .configure(hooks())
  .use(bodyParser.json())
  .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
  .configure(services) // pull in all services from services/index.js
  .configure(middleware) // middleware from middleware/index.js
  .hooks(appHooks)
```

Within services, I first add authentication, which is in its own file and that looks like this
**authentication.js**

```
const authentication = require('feathers-authentication');
const jwt = require('feathers-authentication-jwt');
const local = require('feathers-authentication-local');
const authManagement = require('feathers-authentication-management');

module.exports = function () {

  const app = this;
  const config = app.get('authentication');

  // Set up authentication with the secret
  app.configure(authentication(config));
  app.configure(authManagement(config));
  app.configure(jwt());
  app.configure(local(config.local));

  // The `authentication` service is used to create a JWT.
  // The before `create` hook registers strategies that can be used
  // to create a new valid JWT (e.g. local or oauth2)
  app.service('authentication').hooks({
    before: {
      create: [
        authentication.hooks.authenticate(config.strategies)
      ],
      remove: [
        authentication.hooks.authenticate('jwt')
      ]
    }
  });
```

};

**index.html** (mostly stripped, just showing relevant script)

```
let url = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + 
    (location.port
      ? ':' + location.port
      : '');

const socket = io(url);

const feathersClient = feathers()
  .configure(feathers.socketio(socket))
  .configure(feathers.hooks())
  .configure(feathers.authentication({ storage: window.localStorage }));
```

Here's a screen shot showing some requests in chrome debugger and postman.
[image: Showing chrome debugger err and success, and postman success]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When default.json is set to use 'username' as the usernameField it outputs my Windows username, 'Matt'. This is because feathers-configuration checks to see if a value is a part of the OS environment.

https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-configuration/blob/master/src/index.js#L26

[image: usernameField as username]

### Workaround

Manually set this configuration in authentication.js, for example:

```
  // Set up authentication with the secret
  const localConfig = {
    'entity': 'users',
    'service': 'users',
    'usernameField': 'username',
    'passwordField': 'password'
  }; 

  app.configure(authentication(config));
  app.configure(local(localConfig));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I don't believe this is the problem as I set that. [Here is a repo](https://github.com/snewell92/newhotness) showing my latest progress, and [here is my configuration](https://github.com/snewell92/newhotness/blob/master/config/default.json).

Comment: Actually, when I get back to this project on Monday, I'll try to update my configuration file to match what the `feathers-authentication-local` expects, and I'll look into the source to ensure it's looking where I think it is. The config may not need that `local` property in the `authentication` object....?

Comment: I have rolled back my response because it appears to be a bug. I found your GitHub issue and will investigate more there. J

Comment: Hey @SeanNewell, I've updated my answer to address your problem with a workaround. You might be better using something other than username (eg. user_name, user, etc).

Comment: I also cannot figure out why it worked using REST. I'm not able to replicate that again, so I think it was just a lucky request!